# Using glob twice in a Python script

Tags: python, glob

I have a Python script that I have written that plots data from two different files.  I have several pairs of files over which I need to run this script.  (Take "several pairs" to mean potentially thousands.)  In a similar script that plots data from a single file, I used glob.glob with great success.  I would like to do something similar in this case.

My question is two-fold:

1. Do I need to define a separate function for each glob.glob?
2. Can I nest the second glob.glob within the for loop I used in the single-data-file case, shown here?

   ```
   def process_file(my_file):

   (# The body of my code... not relevant, and not something I can share.

   if __name__=='__main__':
       import glob
       for f in glob.glob(file_directory + "*_data.dat"):
           process_file(f)
           print f
   ```

I've only been programming for a few months, so this is the first time I've had to do something this exotic.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. You can use `glob.glob()` as many times as you want, just like any other function. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: @MattDMo I don't have time to create an MCVE.  I just need to know if I can use glob.glob() in a for loop, and if I would need to define a separate function for each glob.glob().  That seems like a rather universal question, not one that requires an example.

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86: Just do it.  If it doesn't work, then you can begin to ask questions about why it doesn't work, or how to make it work.  People on StackOverflow are not generally going to be interested in answering questions you could answer yourself just by running your code.

Comment: @BrenBarn good to know!  I'll remember in the future that StackOverflow is not helpful for newcomers.

Comment: this is helpful... it's much quicker for you to just try running the code before taking time to write up a question about 'will it work'.

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86: That depends what you mean.  It's helpful for newcomers who have a question they are stuck with.  It's not helpful for getting people to answer questions when it's clear you already have the means to answer them yourself.

Comment: If I had the means of answering it myself, I wouldn't be asking, as it would already be answered.  And I have tried different combinations of commands that I thought would work, which didn't.  I cannot provide my code here, as it is part of my dissertation work, nor can I write an MCVE based on it (for the same reason).  This is something that I have been attempting for the better part of a week, and that is why I thought it would be reasonable to ask for assistance.  So shall I continue asking for help, or should I assume that this question is not answerable?

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86 for future questions, if someone asks for an MCVE, it doesn't need to exactly mirror what your code is doing, or replicate any of your data, or whatever. Simply describe in code what you're trying to do and where you're stuck, in a way that reproduces the results you're getting with your production code. That's it. Many of the questions here are from "newcomers", and they are by no means unwelcome - we simply ask them to understand the rules of the site, and ask clear, on-topic questions that contain enough information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try and answer your questions

> "Do I need to define a separate function for each glob.glob?"

This depends - do you need to do the same thing to both types of file? In which case just use the same function. Otherwise if the operations are quite different you should have two different functions.

If the operations are mostly identical you could have one function, but taking an argument to say what type of file you're passing, eg:

```
def process_file(file_path, file_type):
    # mostly the same stuff
    ...
    if file_type == 'a':
        # something different
```

> "Can I nest the second glob.glob within the for loop I used in the single-data-file case, shown here?"

You could do. Assuming the filenames of the pairs of files are somewhat related you could have something like:

```
for f_a in glob.glob(file_directory + "*_data_a.dat"):
    process_file(f_a, 'a')
    for f_b in glob.glob(file_directory + f_a[:-11] + "_data_b.dat"):
        # we only ever expect to find one item to loop over here though
        process_file(f_b, 'b')
```

But in that case the inner glob is pointless... we have constructed the whole filename in our python code and could just do:

```
for f_a in glob.glob(file_directory + "*_data_a.dat"):
    process_file(f_a, file_type='a')
    process_file(file_directory + f_a[:-11] + "_data_b.dat", file_type='b')
```

Well, strictly speaking the inner glob did do something more than the above, it told you that the second file existed. So we could get that behaviour back by doing:

```
import os

for f_a in glob.glob(file_directory + "*_data_a.dat"):
    process_file(f_a, file_type='a')
    f_b = file_directory + f_a[:-11] + "_data_b.dat"
    if os.path.isfile(f_b):
        process_file(f_b, file_type='b')
```

Comment: thank you!  This is the kind of help I was looking for.  And I'm beginning to see why what I tried was wrong.  Thank you for offering direction.  This is exactly what I was looking for!